# Error copying objects when class contains boost::container::flat_set

Tags: c++, boost, copy-constructor

Under the (false?) impression that `boost::container::flat_set` was a drop-in replacement of `std::set`, I replaced `set` with `flat_set` wherever I expected the number of element to be small and the search performance is more critical than inserts.

At a later stage, I was stumped by a confusing compilation error which I eventually traced to the use of `flat_set` as a class member.

For example:

```
class Room {
  private:
    boost::container::flat_set<int> v;
};
```

The following code will not compile, but works just fine if I replace `flat_set` with `std::set`.

```
Room a;
Room b = Room(); // Example 1. Compiles OK
a = b;           // Example 2. Compiles OK
a = Room();      // Example 3. Eeeek! Compile fails on this line
```

The compilation error I see is:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘a = Room()’
note: candidate is:
note: Room& Room::operator=(Room&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Room’ to ‘Room&’
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is this error expected? If it is, then how do I work round it?
2. How are the three statements in the example code different, and why does only the last one fail?
3. Why does the compiler complain about the assignment operator of `Room` rather than `flat_set`? Has the use of `flat_set` influenced the default operators generated for the class?

---

Complete sample program:

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

class Room {
  private:
    boost::container::flat_set<int> v;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Room a;

  Room b = Room();
  a = b;
  a = Room();  // compilation fails here

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: The error message is about the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. Not that that answers the question...

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be helpful.

Comment: @Robᵩ I have one but still looking to a place to host it (ideone and codepad provides Boost that's too old and hence no flat_set support). For now: http://ideone.com/anLmAb

Comment: Hmm, the error message seems to suggest that Room::operator= takes a `Room&` rather than the usual `const Room&`. If there's nothing else involved, that suggests the same thing about `flat_set`.

Comment: "*How are the three assignments in the example code different?*" - There are only two assignments in the example code. The first is an initializtion, not an assignment.

Comment: @Robᵩ pardon my jargons. I'm relatively new to the C++ world.

Comment: So what happened, I cant compile flat_set either (in vs2012), what can I do?

Comment: @ViktorSehr See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364366/error-copying-objects-when-class-contains-boostcontainerflat-set/13882531#13882531

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the move emulation performed by *Boost.Move*. You can find more information about it here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/move/emulation_limitations.html#move.emulation_limitations.assignment_operator

Comment: Many thanks. That definitely appears to be relevant, however I'm still struggling to understand its implications and find a solution.

Comment: @Shawn Chin: Just define an _assignemnt operator_ for `Room` that takes a _const reference_ argument.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I've tried defining `Room& Room::operator=(const Room &x) {...}` but that doesn't change anything. I'm obviously doing it wrong.

Comment: @Shawn Chin: It should _at least_ change the error message you are getting. Try updating the question or starting a new one.

Comment: Oopps. sorry, my bad. I was overloading the operation outside the class definition rather than as a class member. Progress!

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:*** I am the OP; I've accepted [K-ballo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364366/error-copying-objects-when-class-contains-boostcontainerflat-set/13364536#13364536) as it led to the final solution, and I'm posting this to supplement this thread with some details.

As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is indeed a [known limitation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/move/emulation_limitations.html#move.emulation_limitations.assignment_operator) for classes that use the [BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE macro](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE.html) (which applies to many of the classes in `boost::container` including `flat_set` and `flat_map`).

To overcome this, I defined an assignment operator for the class which takes a const reference argument. For example, in the case of the sample `Room` class in the quesiton it would be along the lines of:

```
class Room {
  private:
    boost::container::flat_set<int> v;

  public:
    Room& operator=(const Room& source) {
      v = source.v;
      return *this;
    }
};
```